# Thymeleaf LD+JSON output quote escaped

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am generating LD+JSON string on server and I need to output it on client using Thyemeleaf.

Generated JSON looks like this on server:

```
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity" : [ {
    "@type" : "Question",
    "name" : "question text",
    "acceptedAnswer" : {
      "@type" : "Answer",
      "text" : "answer text <a href=\"\">link</a> answer text."
    }
```

As you can see the text is properly formatted on server. I render it on client like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" th:utext="${faqsJson}">
```

But the output in HTML looks like this:

```
{

  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity" : [ {
    "@type" : "Question",
    "name" : "question text",
    "acceptedAnswer" : {
      "@type" : "Answer",
      "text" : "answer text <a href="\&quot;\&quot;"> answer text."
    }
```

As you can see `<a href` is not properly escaped. For some reason it adds `&quot;` into the href attribute and does not escape double quote.

How can I force Thymeleaf to output the string exactly as it should look like?

Comment: Not sure about the use of the `script` tag in the above example - that would not generate any output on the page.  Did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: It has to be part of `script` ... output on the page is not needed. It is just for the search engine to grab these infromation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the literal text in your HTML page, you can use `th:inline="text"` - and to preserve the line breaks you can also use `white-space: pre-wrap;`:

```
<div th:inline="text" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">[[${faqsJson}]]</div>
```

The resulting HTML display is this on the browser page:

[image]

See [text inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#text-inlining) for reference.

Don't leave any white space between the `>` in the div tag and the `[` at the start of the Thymeleaf expression - otherwise that will become white space on the HTML page.

Comment: Thanks, adding `th:inline="text"` and then using `[[${faqsJson}]]` helped. So my code is following:      `<script type="application/ld+json" th:inline="text">[[${faqsJson}]]</script>`